# Sluggish performance in matplotlib funcAnimation and Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I’m having some trouble getting decent performance out of my Tkinter App with a Matplotlib animation (of serial port data from Arduino) on anything other than a high-performance desktop which makes me think I’m doing something inefficient.

The app works as I want it to and everything displays correctly, its just rather laggy. Based on tests, this seems to be a problem with the matplotlib implementation and when the animation is running everything slows right down. I have tried turning blitting on in funcanimation but this doesn't appear to make a difference. when its just Tkinter with no graph, its snappy.

The flip side to this is when i'm running just the graph (i.e. not wrapped in a gui), everything seems to work relatively smoothly. Could this be the TkAgg backend perhaps? or is Tkinter competing with resources the graphing is eating up refreshing the line?

```
import matplotlib
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import tkFileDialog
import serial
import io
import os
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
from matplotlib import style
from serialFunctions import findArduino #custom function to identify arduino from com port address
```

The matplotlib code for funcanimation:

```
fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot(np.random.rand(10), color = 'red', label = 'Velocity (cm/s)')
sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(arduino, arduino, 1))

#Data Update
tmin = 0.0
tmax = 10.0

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def run(data):
    t, y = data
    #print t , y
    xdata.append(t)
    ydata.append(y)
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)

    if t >= tmax- 1.00:
        line.axes.set_xlim(t - tmax + 1.0, t + 1.0)

    return line,

def data_gen():
    '''Generator to pass data to the run function via funcanimation'''
    t = 0
    while True:
        t+=0.1
        try:
            dat = float(sio.readline())
            # print dat
        except:
            dat = 0
        yield t, dat

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, data_gen, init_func = init, interval=20, blit=False)
```

The Tkinter relevant code:

```
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

class StreamPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, {'bg': '#020b19'})

        label = tk.Label(self, text = 'Begin Streaming', font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)

        backButton = ttk.Button(self, text = 'Back', 
                                command = lambda: 
                                controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        backButton.pack()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)

        canvas.show()

        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = tk.TOP, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)

        #toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)

        #toolbar.update()

        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side = tk.TOP, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)
```

The Arduino Code

```
int const potPin = A0;
int potVal;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  analogReference(DEFAULT); //EXTERNAL NO MORE THAN 5V!
  Serial.begin(1200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  potVal = analogRead(potPin);

  float voltage = potVal * (5.0/1024.0); 
  Serial.print(voltage);
  Serial.print('\n');
}
```

Comment: "sluggish performance" is not a good problem description. Try to find out which part of the code takes the most time and focus your question on that part.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have refined this a little and it seems to be the implementation of the funcanimation. When this is active, both the animation itself and Tkinter slows right down and becomes very unresponsive. When separated, each component works well. Its as if each component is competing for processing time.

Comment: Please, add all the 'import' that are necessary to run your code... Also, I had a laggy 3D plot using matplotlib a while ago. Performace was greatly improved when I switched to [myavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/); maybe your performance would improve if you switched? (requires python 2.7.)

Comment: I have added all my imports for this. ive not heard of myavi but ill check it out. Did you integrate this with Tkinter?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same performance issue, and found good suggestions here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200629013501/http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-performance.htm

Calling update_idletasks in the run function improved the performance significantly for me.